# Not able to load xml/config file into my xslt file

Tags: xml, web, configuration, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to consume the configuration values from external xml file into my XSLT file.

**<xsl:apply-templates select="document("\test\test.xml")/>**
**Error**:
Execution of the document function prohibited

Use the **XslSettings.EnableDocumentFunction** property to enable it.
Can anyone help me on this? how to load xml values into my xslt so that i can dynamically use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds as if you use XSLT 1.0 with Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform`, as the message tells you use `XsltSettings` with `EnableDocumentFunction` set to true e.g. `var xsltProcessor = new XslCompiledTransform(); xsltProcessor.Load("sheet1.xsl", new XsltSettings(true, false), new XmlUrlResolver());`.

Comment: Can we make this setting in xslt rather than in dotnet?

Comment: In XSLT? No, that is a setting that needs to be used programmatically with the `XslCompiledTransform.Load` method.

Comment: The whole point of having the setting is to enable you to execute untrusted XSLT code; allowing it to be set from within the XSLT would defeat the purpose.